# Is there a way to run top as a daemon to gather historical process data?

Tags: linux, monitoring, top, system-monitoring

I am aware that I can write a cron job that will run top in batch mode and write the output to a file but I am looking for something more elegant than that. Also I am aware of sysstat (sar) but I am looking for more detailed process data.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: What about running periodically `ps`? This command seems to be much more suitable for what you plan.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - can you expand a little more

Comment: If a snapshot of running processes once in a while is what you're looking for, you could run `ps -ef >> logfile` from cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into `atop`, which runs a daemon and keeps historical data for every process. You made need to do some tweaking to keep an archive, but that's my other tool of choice besides `sar`.